# Setting up and testing a pre-commit hook in SVN running on Linux machine which I access remotely

Tags: linux, bash, svn, pre-commit-hook, svn-hooks

I'm gonna try to be as forthcoming as I can about my problem.

I'm on a Windows computer. The SVN repository is on a Linux machine.

I access the Linux machine remotely, using Putty and logging in as root. Everything is done through the command line.

Now, I have to set up a pre-commit hook that won't allow special characters like [éáú] on source code files. In order to do that, I set out to find out how to setup a pre-commit hook.

Here's what I've done:

1. Found a script
2. Went to the hooks folder in the repository. Removed the extension of the file *pre-commit.tmpl*
3. Pasted the script there and saved
4. Ran the chmod command on file *pre-commit.tmpl*

Then I tried commiting a change to the repository and I got:

**Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 255) with no output**

Alright, I figured something was wrong in how I set up the pre-commit file, so I removed the script and added a simple echo "hello world".

Now the commit goes through, but the echo message doesn't show up at all. If I put *exit 1* at the end of the script, I get error code 1 and the echo message still doesn't show up.

I have literally searched high and low on the internet and have found no solution to my problem.

What I need:

- An explanation as to why the echo messages are not showing up
- If possible, a step-by-step on how to set up and test a simple script

For example, I've seen a lot of scripts where there's something like this:

> `#!/bin/bash`
>   `REPOS="$1"`
>   `TXN="$2"`

What am I supposed to put in REPOS and in TXN? I assume in REPOS I should put the repository path? What about TXN?

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: `$1` and `$2` are variables representing the first and second arguments to the script. Presumably SVN runs your script with those correctly. You don't need to do anything there most likely. What those *mean* depends on the hook and the SVN hook documentation should tell you.

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html

Comment: I've already read that Etan, it didn't help.

Actually, not even something as simple as 
echo "hello world"
exit 1
is working

Comment: Did you see the bit about `standard error`?

Comment: In that page, or in the SVN book in general? What I really want to do now is at least make the echo message show up. It's so simple yet I can't get it to come out. I tried in Windows and in the Linux machine, no dice. _echo "Testing" >&2_. Why doesn't this work grrr?

Comment: Did you output to stderr *and* exit with a failure? Because that's what the docs say you should need to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Billet of the pre-commit hook (*Nix-adopted)**

Always failing

> ```
> #!/bin/bash 
> echo You failed 1>&2
> exit 1
> ```

commit sample

```
>svn commit -m "Changes"
Sending        Folder1\Folder2\Folder3
Sending        Folder4
svn: E165001: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E165001: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
You failed
```

Note **correct** redirection of output in `echo`

About $REPO and $TXN (already linked) SVN Book chapter have full explanation

> The command-line arguments passed to the hook program, in order, are:
>
> 1. Repository path
> 2. Commit transaction name

because these parameters are needed for most often used in pre-commit hooks commands, like svnlook